# How to Generate multiple HTML reports bases on Thread Count in JMETER using "Ultimate Thread Count"?

Tags: jmeter

I have set up multiple thread counts in "Ultimate thread group". After execution in non GUI mode only one csv file and one html report gets generated. Is there any option to generate multiple html reports based on Thread Count.? or can we generate multiple repors from the single csv file?

The command that i used to generate the result csv file and html report is:
jmeter -n -t "path of the filename.jmx" -l "path of the result in csv format" -e -o "path of html report"

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b6CUR.png)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what do you mean by "bases on Thread Count".

JMeter's [.jtl result file](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/jmeter/JtlFiles) is normal [CSV file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) and it has the following columns which may be interesting to you:

- `timeStamp` request start time in milliseconds since [Unix epoch](https://www.unixtimestamp.com/)
- `grpThreads` - the number of active threads in current Thread Group
- `allThreads` - the number of active threads across Thread Groups

If you want to split your .jtl file into several smaller ones you can do this using i.e. [Filter Results Tool](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/FilterResultsTool/) which provides `start-offset` and `end-offset` parameters so you can "cut" the .jtl file into pieces according to your requirements and generate reporting dashboard for each of these "pieces"

Filter Results Tool can be installed using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-plugins-manager)

Comment: by "bases on Thread Count" I mean inside "Thread Schedule" we add number of "Start Thread Count" (I have added the screenshot of the thread "jp@gc - Ultimate Thread Group" in my original post.

I have added "Filter Results Tool" but unable to process the command as mentioned in the Jmeter Page. Can you please help me with one live example command and in which directory I must open the cmd ?